# CDS Annotation fieldGroup has no affect on Smart Template

Tags: sapui5

When creating my CDS view the following code places the attribute in the object view:

```
@UI.identification: [ {position: 10, importance: #HIGH, label: 'Booking Price'} ]
key sbook.forcuram as bookingprice
```

However, when using

```
@UI.fieldGroup: [ { qualifier: 'Payment', position: 10 } ]
key sbook.forcuram as bookingprice
```

It is not in a group with the name Payment in the object page as described in the document CDS Annotations for Metadata-Driven UIs. Instead, it doesnt appear at all (and the document mentioned nothing else than the example I provided as, the 2nd code snipped).

Using both annotations results in the fieldGroup one being completely ignored as well.

What do I need to do?

Comment: The question does not seem to be clear, what document are you referring to?

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla "CDS Annotations for Metadata-Driven UIs", being equal to [this page](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/72/dd334ff1ba4681959fa2b873a0a415/content.htm)

Comment: I don't think the qualifier label is meant to be used like that, it just is an identifier for your annotation and  all the annotations with the same qualifier name will be grouped under one parent.

Now from the example the sales order ID value appears because of the statement key so.sales_order_id as SalesOrder,

so in your UI you will get the value of booking price under forcuram.

I hope I was clear.

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla I have customer.telephone and customer.email which I would like to group under Personal Information & booking.forcuram and booking.forcurkey under Payment. So what do I have to use as the qualifier? I tried the example from the website 1:1 (same view) and it also didn't work

Comment: The qualifier can be any random set of characters, I assume you are using some sort of template which will need these annotations as input, so for the particular field, you will have to give the qualifier name, for example if your item requires a fieldGroup annotation, then you will have to specify like 

......FieldGroup#qualifier1

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla I use the Smart Template with list report and object page. The webide looks like that: [PICTUR](https://answers.sap.com/storage/attachments/15888-anno.png).I thought smart templates will generate the groups automatically?

Comment: I am not too sure about list report and object page, could you tell me what you are trying to achieve exactly? Maybe I will be able to help you out better

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla So basically I am using Fiori Elements/Smart Templates (aka no UI coding). Now every attribute I mark with UI.identification is displayed under the general information label. Reading the doumentation (link I provided) UI.fieldGroup: should allow me to group attributes together so the UI does look better than having everything below eachother. But that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @DwarakeshPallagolla Seems like Facets are not yet supported with annotations. Sad

Comment: I guess you can post it as an answer then! Might help someone looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it is not (yet) supported to add Facets to CDS views. In order to make it work, I had to manually add a UI.ReferenceFacet in the WebIDE with the target annotation being '@UI.FieldGroup#Payment'.